# Strange behaviour with snippets

Tags: sxa

I have a page where I added a Snippet Rendering to a Page in the main placeholder.  I created a global datasource for the snippet.  I then dragged renderings onto the snippet such as image and rich text and clicked save.

My snippet renderings disappear!

[image: Where are my snippet renderings?]

Looking at my data item in the content tree - I can see what I dragged on prior to saving.

[image]

Not sure why in Experience Editor I'm not seeing those fields as renderings to edit.

Comment: I've checked this on the current code (the one which will be included in 1.8.1) and it works fine. I would need to confirm this on 1.8 because this is the version you are using, I'm I, right?

Comment: I've also checked in 1.8 and working as expected

Comment: Yeah it is 1.8.

Comment: You might want to check your sitecore logs or the console for any errors that might be happening during the save event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golden rule is save immediately after adding your Snippet.  I was trying to add the snippet and then add the renderings inside that snippet before I had clicked Save and so was getting strange behaviour.